# How to create a keybinding using the [fn] key as a modifier?

Tags: keyboard

The half-size arrow keys on my MacBook are a little small for me. The keys I'd prefer to use are:

- <kbd>fn</kbd> +  <kbd>J</kbd>  *to move left*
- <kbd>fn</kbd> +  <kbd>K</kbd>  *to move down*
- <kbd>fn</kbd> +  <kbd>L</kbd>  *to move right*
- <kbd>fn</kbd> +  <kbd>I</kbd>  *to move up*

I badly want to use the "fn" key for this, both for ergonomic and practical reasons (ie: avoid conflicts with other apps).

Is this possible? How?

Comment: To clarify: I know how to do this using the ctrl key, the shift key, the alt key... unfortunately the *function* key seems to be off limits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I installed a third party utility to remap these keys on my MacBook Pro running OS X 10.8. **Here are the steps I used:**

(1) **[Download](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook) and install KeyRemap4MacBook.app**

(2) **Edit** (or create) the following file in a text editor:

```
~/Library/Application Support/KeyRemap4MacBook/private.xml
```

...so that its content is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<item>
        <name>JKLI to Arrow Keys</name>
        <identifier>private.jkli_to_arrow_keys</identifier>
        <autogen>
            __KeyToKey__
            KeyCode::J, ModifierFlag::FN,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT
        </autogen>
        <autogen>
        __KeyToKey__
            KeyCode::K, ModifierFlag::FN,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN
        </autogen>
        <autogen>
        __KeyToKey__
            KeyCode::L, ModifierFlag::FN,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT
        </autogen>
        <autogen>
        __KeyToKey__
            KeyCode::I, ModifierFlag::FN,
            KeyCode::CURSOR_UP
        </autogen>
</item>
</root>
```

(3) **Select "Preferences" from** the little **KeyRemap4MacBook icon in** the OS X **MenuBar** at the top of the screen.

[image: KeyRemap4MacBook > Preferences]

(4) In KeyRemap4MacBook's **"Change Key" tab**, **tick "JKLI to Arrow Keys".** (if this option doesn't appear, you may need to click the "ReloadXML" button)

[image: KeyRemap4MacBook > Change Key]

**You should now be able to use the Function key with J|K|L|I to control the cursor, in addition to the Arrow keys.**

Comment: KeyRemap4MacBook is now called Karabiner: https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/

Answer (score 2):

You are correct.  Although Mac OS X allows you to remap the <kbd>control</kbd>, <kbd>caps lock</kbd>, <kbd>option</kbd>, and <kbd>command</kbd> keys, the <kbd>fn</kbd> key is not included.  To do this, you'll need to use 3rd-party software such as [DoubleCommand](http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/).  That will let you remap the <kbd>fn</kbd> key to the <kbd>control</kbd> key.

From there, you should check out additional software to remap the <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> key etc. to emulate the left key etc. So long as you can emulate <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, you should be able to create the keybinding in ~/Library/KeyBindings. You might be able to do this last step in DoubleCommand as well.

Comment: Not sure DoubleCommand works with Lion, I'll check this out. If it does, this would indeed be a solution, because OS X allows you to add keybindings ( ~/Library/KeyBindings ) with [ctrl]

Comment: Very cool.  You should edit my answer to add that information!

Comment: Update for those coming to this in 2015:
KeyRemap4MacBook.app has been renamed and is available at [1]: https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner

Answer (score 1):

This is possible on macOS Catalina without any extra software by using System preferences -> Keyboard.

Hit the <kbd>Modifier</kbd> button, and you can now change the behaviour of your <kbd>fn</kbd> key to <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Option</kbd>, <kbd>Command</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Interestingly, you cannot so easily modify any of those keys to act as the <kbd>fn</kbd> key.

Comment: What os? Mojave or Catalina only?

Comment: Good question, I'm running Catalina, I never made any changes when I had Mojave, so can't say for sure.

Comment: Perfect, go with what you know. I’d vote up again, but already did that on version 1 of the post. Thanks!