# Macos Monterey update broke my Fn-a Emacs keybind; how to disable it?

Tags: macos, keybindings, monterey

I am resigned to moving the keybind to Fn-x, but just in case there's an easy way to disable it, I thought I'd ask.

Eminent domain!  Eat the rich!

[How to create a keybinding using the [fn] key as a modifier?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48096/how-to-create-a-keybinding-using-the-fn-key-as-a-modifier)

Not what I want.